# Como recupero el resultado de una consulta mysql desde Ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

             var Numero_Empleado = $("#numeroEmpleadoNotificacion").val();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url: "notificaciones.php",
                 async:true,
                 data: { "Numero_Empleado": Numero_Empleado },
                 success: function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                     
                 }
             })

     });
```

De la cual en la instrucción `alert(data)` me regresa la consulta que se encuentra en el archivo notificaciones.php,  y lo que quisiera saber es como puedo recuperar el resultado de esa consulta para darle utilidad a los valores obtenidos. La consulta que me aparece en la pantalla que lanza el alert, se ha probado en un Query Browser y funciona sin problema obteniendo los valores definidos en dicha consulta.

El código contenido en notificaciones.php es el siguiente:

```
 if (isset ($_POST['Numero_Empleado'])){

        $Numero_Empleado=strip_tags($_POST['Numero_Empleado']);

        $instanciaPersistenciaBienesNotificacion = new notificaciones();
        $instanciaNegocioBienesNotificacion = new n_notificaciones();
        $resultadoBienesNotificacion=$instanciaNegocioBienesNotificacion->n_Consulta_Notificaciones($Numero_Empleado);
        $totalResultadoBienesNotificacion=count($resultadoBienesNotificacion);

    }
```

el cual manda llamar a la consulta `n_Consulta_Notificaciones`  la cual contiene este código:

```
"SELECT
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Id_Bien AS ID_BIEN,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Activo AS ACTIVO,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.SubActivo AS SUBACTIVO,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual AS NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Empleado_Movimiento  AS EMPLEADO_MOVIMIENTO,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Notificacion_Asignacion  AS NOTIFICACION,
        COUNT(patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Notificacion_Asignacion) AS NUMERO_NOTIFICACION,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Validacion_Asignacion  AS VALIDACION,
        patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Fecha_Asignacion  AS FECHA_ASIGNACION,
        concat_ws(' ', plantilla.plantilla.nombre , plantilla.plantilla.apellido1 ,plantilla.plantilla.apellido2) AS NOMBRE
        FROM  patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion
        INNER JOIN plantilla.plantilla ON patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual = plantilla.plantilla.numero_empleado
        WHERE patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual = '$Numero_Empleado'";

        $resultadoNotificacionesAsignacion = $this->consultaSelect($consulta);
        $contador = 0;
        while ($registro = $resultadoNotificacionesAsignacion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador] = new notificaciones();
        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setCadenaFecha_Asignacion(utf8_encode($registro['FECHA_ASIGNACION']));
        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroNotificacion(utf8_encode($registro['NOTIFICACION']));
        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroValidacionNotificacion(utf8_encode($registro['VALIDACION']));
        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroNumeroNotificaciones(utf8_encode($registro['NUMERO_NOTIFICACION']));
        $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setCadenaNombre(utf8_encode($registro['NOMBRE']));
        $contador++;
    }
    return $listaNotificacionesAsignacion;
```

Tengo un ejemplo que encontré ayer en la web:

```js
function ver(){

    $.ajax({ //se inicia la petición ajax al archivo que consulta los mensajes en la base de datos
        type : 'GET', //consulta mediante get
        url : 'consulta_msg.php', //url del archivo a consultar
        data : {'id_propietario':'1'}, //consulta el id del propietario
        dataType : 'json', //se espera retornar un json
        success : function(data) { //si fue satisfactorio la petición ajax retorna la variable data con la información
            $.each(data, function(i, item) { //recorremos el json para obtener los mensajes
                var texto = item.texto;
                var emisor = item.emisor;
                var num_msg = item.num_msg;
                
                if(num_msg>0){
                
                    Push.create(emisor, { //llamamos al objeto push escrito en jquery
                        body: texto, //ingresamos el texto recuperado de la petición ajax
                        timeout: 4000, //con este valor indica que despues de 4000 ms se cierre automaticamente el mensaje
                        onClick: function () { //al hacer click en la notificación se cerrará
                            window.focus();
                            this.close();
                        }
                    });
                }
                
            });
        },
    });

}
```

pero a mi no me ha funcionado adaptándolo a mis necesidades.

Comment: Pon el código de tu otro archivo

Comment: Generalmente se suele enviar un json desde el servidor y luego en el `success` de Ajax lees ese json y lo muestras donde lo necesites. De todos modos, sin ver lo que devuelves desde el servidor y sin que expliques cómo lo quieres mostrar y dónde poco más podemos decirte. Si  vas a enviar json desde el servidor debes poner `dataType: 'json'` en tu petición Ajax, donde pones `url` y `data`

Comment: Debes mandar los resultados de tu archivo en formato json, capturarlos en tu función AJAX y luego darles uso en donde requieras.

Comment: @A.Cedano , agrego el dataType, pero no se como recuperar el Json, encontré un ejemplo muy similar a lo que quiero hacer pero a mi no me funciona este es el codigo:  success: function(data){$.each(data, function(i, item) { //recorremos el json para obtener los mensajes
    var texto = item.texto;
    var emisor = item.emisor;
    var num_msg = item.num_msg;
    
    if(num_msg>0){ }

Comment: La lectura del JSON depende de lo que estés mandando desde el servidor. Usarías each si estuvieras mandando un array de objetos JSON, si es un solo objeto no hace falta each, sino que leerías directamente poniendo por ejemplo `data.propiedad` donde `propiedad` sería cualquier propiedad de tu JSON, como emisor, texto, etc. Testea lo que recibes desde el servidor para saber cómo tienes que leerlo. Como ya te hemos señalado, falta ver el código de servidor para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya actualice la pregunta.  Saludos

Comment: Por favor, no pongas codigo que no es JS dentro de un contenedor JS.. de esa forma, se pierde el formato y el coloreado del codigo...

Comment: Es mas.. tu pregunta es sobre js o php???

Comment: Pero, ¿qué se supone que es `$listaNotificacionesAsignacion` es un array con datos. De ser así, deberías retornarlo con `json_encode` De todos modos no queda claro el uso contextual, deberías depurar los datos, tanto a nivel de servidor como a nivel de cliente para verificar si estás recibiendo algo y con qué formato o estructura.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si $listaNotificacionesAsignacion es donde se guardan los resultados de la consulta , ya hice un debug en la corrida obtiene los datos que se requiere, lo único que me hace falta es poder rescatarlos para que los pueda utilizar dentro del mismo script donde esta el Ajax, para mostrar una notificación, muy similar al ejemplo que se incluyo al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya, pero no me has respondido si eso es un array o qué es. Eso es fundamental para poder saber lo que estás obteniendo ahí.

Comment: Si es un Array  $listaNotificacionesAsignacion = array(); esta linea no lo agregue esta ubicada entre el nombre de la función y la $consulta = "SELECT";

Comment: Bien, entonces donde recibes el resultado de `$listaNotificacionesAsignacion` debes hacer un `echo json_encode($laVariableQueRecuperaElResultado);` Dado que usas un `count()` ahí ya me pierdo, no entiendo muy bien qué intentas con ese count ¿? Si tú haces un echo del array usando json_encode recuperarás la respuesta como JSON en Ajax y podrás leer los datos sin problemas. Como ya dije más arriba, si son varias filas, usarías `each` para leer cada fila, y si es una fila, buscas la propiedad directamente en `data`

Comment: Si te refieres a este $totalResultadoBienesNotificacion=count($resultadoBienesNotificacion); lo que hace es contar la cantidad de resultados, esto me ha servido como una especie de indice para poder mostrar en modales, las dataTables, y en vistas que requiera imprimir algun valor que se trae desde de la consulta de la BD.

Comment: Me parece complicado poder ayudarte si  no explicas con claridad el contexto. Empecemos desde cero... No estamos ante tu pantalla ni estamos en tu mente para saber cómo funciona tu programa. Una petición Ajax es algo muy simple: mandas a pedir algo al servidor (pasándole datos  o no), si pasas datos, el servidor recupera esos datos (como criterios de búsqueda por ejemplo), procesa lo que le estás pidiendo y te lo devuelve. Eso que el servidor devuelve lo recuperas en `success` y lo muestras o haces lo que quieras hacer con ello. ¿Tienes claro que Ajax funciona de esa forma?

Comment: La petición Ajax, hace su tarea, obtiene un valor, lo pasa por el método POST al archivo indicado, ahí se recibe y se hace la petición de que se ejecute una consulta que se encuentra en otro archivo, esta consulta recibe el parámetro y obtiene los valores que se necesitan en base a ese parámetro. En el success es precisamente donde no se que hacer, ya que no se como recuperar los valores que se obtienen de la consulta.

Comment: En el Ajax, ya agregue la linea "dataType: 'json'"  al final de la consulta ya hice el cambio echo json_encode($listaNotificacionesAsignacion);, en la ventana de alerta ahora me aparece [object Object].  en lugar de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo la manera en que pude resolver esta pregunta por si alguna persona en algún momento tiene la misma inquietud. Quizás no sea lo mas prolijo pero funciona y hace lo que necesito.

En cuanto a la petición Ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         var Numero_Empleado = $("#numeroEmpleadoNotificacion").val();
        
         $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "notificaciones.php",
             async:true,
             data: { "Numero_Empleado": Numero_Empleado },
             success: function(data) {
                 //console.log(data);
                 //alert(data);
              var datosNotifica = JSON.parse(data); // Se decodifica el Json.
              for(var i in datosNotifica.data){  // Se crea el ciclo para realizar el recorrido
                  //console.log(datosNotifica.data[i]);
                 // Se crean variables y asignan los valores
                  var Notificacion = datosNotifica.data[i].NOTIFICACION; 
                  var Nombre = datosNotifica.data[i].NOMBRE;
                  var Notificaciones = datosNotifica.data[i].NUMERO_NOTIFICACION;
                 
                 // Aquí validamos que se tenga un resultado, si existe envía el push notification.
                  if (Notificacion>0){
                      Push.create("Si puedes ver este mensaje es que lo hiciste bien", {
                          body: "Estimado: " +Nombre+ " Tienes " +Notificaciones+ " Activo(s) Nuevo(s) Asignado(s) ",
                          icon: "",
                          timeout: 8000,
                          onClick: function () {
                              window.location = "algunaPagina.php"
                              this.close();
                          }
                      });
                  }
              }
             }
         })

     });
```

En lo que corresponde a la consulta:

```
"SELECT
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Id_Bien AS ID_BIEN,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Activo AS ACTIVO,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.SubActivo AS SUBACTIVO,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual AS NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Empleado_Movimiento  AS EMPLEADO_MOVIMIENTO,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Notificacion_Asignacion AS NOTIFICACION,
    COUNT(patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Notificacion_Asignacion) AS NUMERO_NOTIFICACION,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Validacion_Asignacion  AS VALIDACION,
    patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Fecha_Asignacion  AS FECHA_ASIGNACION,
    concat_ws(' ', plantilla.plantilla.nombre , plantilla.plantilla.apellido1 ,plantilla.plantilla.apellido2) AS NOMBRE
    FROM  patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion
    INNER JOIN plantilla.plantilla ON patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual = plantilla.plantilla.numero_empleado
    WHERE patrimonial.auxiliar_asignacion.Resguardo_Actual = '$Numero_Empleado'";

    $resultadoNotificacionesAsignacion = $this->consultaSelect($consulta);
    $contador = 0;
    while ($registro = $resultadoNotificacionesAsignacion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador] = new notificaciones();
    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setCadenaFecha_Asignacion(utf8_encode($registro['FECHA_ASIGNACION']));
    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroNotificacion(utf8_encode($registro['NOTIFICACION']));
    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroValidacionNotificacion(utf8_encode($registro['VALIDACION']));
    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setEnteroNumeroNotificaciones(utf8_encode($registro['NUMERO_NOTIFICACION']));
    $listaNotificacionesAsignacion[$contador]->setCadenaNombre(utf8_encode($registro['NOMBRE']));
    $contador++;
    $resultado["data"][]=$registro; //<<-- Se añade esta linea para darle forma a la estructura de salida de los datos//

}
echo json_encode($resultado); // <<-- Se añade esta linea para codificar en Json.
//return $listaNotificacionesAsignacion;  // <<-- Esta la comentas o eliminas
```

Y pues de esta manera es como en el caso que se detecte una notificacion en la tabla que se indica, pues envía el push , falta realizar algunas pruebas para ver como se comporta en el caso de que existan mas de una notificacion por usuario.

Por lo pronto funciona.

Gracias